# Several UIs accessing one (server) proecess - which IPC?

Tags: c++, linux, ipc, shared-memory, dbus

I'm new here and I have a question which I could not find answered by searching.

I've written a program accessing a database in C++ on Linux. Now I would like to be able to give different UI processes (graphical (possible Qt) interface, console UI, web UI) access to this data - with client processes running on the same machine as the server. Which IPC methods would you recommend?

I looked into it, but mostly found sockets recommended - maybe, but not needed now.
The second best thing I found was D-BUS.

Is there any "best practices" or howto? Is there any criteria I should heed to chose a method?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Sounds like 'standard' DB client-server design.  DB normally handle this easily.  Could you explain your problem more clearly?  What DB?

Comment: Sockets sound reasonable.  Shared-memory is good for super high bandwidth but for most apps don't need the bandwidth and shared memory is challenging.

Comment: Just so you know, D-BUS is a layer _on top_ of other IPC frameworks. It might even use sockets for its communication.